# Is Kibana's scripted field working in runtime?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, runtime, kibana, countif

I need to implement a **`countif(range, criteria)`** like the field in Kibana's scripted Field.

My concern is:

**Is this Scripted Field can able to get the total range of the data in real-time as the data will be appending in real-time?**

Comment: Yes, it can....

Answer (score 0):

Indeed,

> Kibana Scripted Field are **computed at query time**, so they aren’t
>   indexed and cannot be searched using the Kibana default query
>   language.

So, yes, as soon as you request a query in Kibana, scripted fields are calculated on the fly. You juste have to keep in mind that scripted field can be very resource intensive and if there is an other method to do the same thing you should favor this one

For the countif query you can do something like this :

```
def counter = 0;

for(int i=0; i < params['_source']['your_field'].length;i++){
    if(params['_source']['your_field'][i] == 'criteria') counter++;
}

return counter;
```

Note that you have to access your field with the params['_source'] ['your_field'] and not with doc['your_field'] because you cannot count the number of occurrences with the indexed field as it reduces all same occurrences to a single value

You can have more information on the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html)

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer Luc E. Can you please show a sample of countif() formula in kibana's Scripted field format? As I could not figure out how to write this in Lucene language.

Comment: So if i understand well, you have a field that is an array of string and want to count the number of occurrence for a particular criteria?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely.

Comment: I added the script on the answer

Comment: Thank You so much Luc E. I'll try to implement your code.